# C# Performance Counter Error

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I create a new performance counter and gave it three things, Processor time, Total and Processor Information. However It gives me an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.dll

Code:

```
PerformanceCounter CpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("% Processor Time", "_Total", "Processor Information");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Anything in the internal exception?

Comment: when that code is run i get an "Category does not exist" within the exception... sounds like you're providing a bad category.  I hate when functions expect string values hehehe.

Comment: Does it matter with the order of the category? Thats the only error it gives me.

Comment: @user3812866 I don't really understand what you're asking with "order of category", if you mean the order of parameters, then yes it does matter.  If you hit F12 on PerformanceCounter as you have above, you can see in the metadata that the first parameter expected is the category

Comment: Pass the strings in the right order: Category, Counter, Instance.  So it is new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total")

Comment: This now shows u Additional information: Could not locate Performance Counter with specified category name 'Processor Information', counter name '% Perforance Time'.